# Regex to capture ( Or ) - the basic command doesn't work

Tags: java, regex

I have trying catch the parentheses in a expression, but I have no success.

I use this regex:

```
  "(\\()|(\\))"
```

but doen't work.

How I do this.

I use this in a split function.

I input this String:

```
"(N >= 20)"
```

and I need this split:

```
 (
 N
 >=
 20
 )
```

I can split N, >=, 20, but I can't split (, the regex doen't match or split the parentheses

Comment: What do you mean by "[it] doesn't work"? What are you trying to match? Input vs output?

Comment: Look again, please. I really need your help.

Comment: Please describe your problem so we can help. Right now we have no way of knowing what you tried or what's not working.

Comment: Look again, please. Understand now?

Comment: No, your question is lacking many important details.

Comment: You probably can't use a single regex for splitting here, because you are splitting on different criteria in different places though you could use a regex to extract the various parts as regex groups.

Comment: Post this in the SOpt :)

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression is a terrible solution for what you're trying to do.  This is an XY problem.

You should be using an infix arithmetic algorithm, like [this one](http://www.smccd.net/accounts/hasson/C++2Notes/ArithmeticParsing.html) in C++.

> Parsing an Infix Expression with Parentheses (like
>   ((2*4-6/3)*(3*5+8/4))-(2+3))
>
> One stack is required. The algorithm is:
>
> Have a string available to store items
>
> For each item in the infix (with parens) expression
>
> If the item is a number then add it to the string with a space
>
> if the item is an operator then
>
> While the stack is not empty and an operator is at the top and the
>   operator at the top is higher priority that the item then
>
> = Pop the operator on the top of the stack
>
> = Add the popped operator to the string with a space
>
> Push the item on the stack
>
> else if the item is a left paren
>
> Push the item on the stack
>
> else if the item is a right paren
>
> Pop a thing off of the stack.
>
> while that thing is not a left paren
>
> = Add the thing to the string with a space
>
> = Pop a thing off of the stack
>
> While the stack is not empty
>
> Pop a thing off the stack.
>
> Add it to the string with a space.
>
> Remove the last character (a space) from the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match ) or (, use the regexp [()].

Comment: It doesn't work. when I add this in my code, the >= stop work and print > and before =, and the parentheses doesn't is printed.

Comment: @user2752929 We have no idea what your code is. How are we supposed to know what's wrong with it?